# Node paths come through empty unless view result is programmatically changed

Tags: views, 8

Task: to retrieve a list of nodes in JSON format including their aliases generated by Pathauto module. The configuration of my view is this:

[image]

Problem: path fields come empty - they won't include original Drupal path to it nor an alias generated by Pathauto:

[image: Path is an empty array]

The current solution I've got is to programmatically amend view's result in the following way:

```
function my_custom_views_pre_render(\Drupal\views\ViewExecutable $view) {
foreach($view->result as $value) {
    $url = \Drupal\Core\Url::fromRoute('entity.node.canonical', ['node' => $value->_entity->get('nid')->value], ['absolute' => false]);
    $url = $url->toString();
    $value->_entity->set('path', $url);
}
```

}

And that populates the path fields:

[image: Path is populated]

I'd like to know if there is a way to avoid the hook and make views return node paths without it, or is it normal Drupal Views behaviour?

P.s.: If I chose "Fields" instead of "Entity" in the Format section in the Views UI, it does return me the correct paths. However I want to get the full entity due to extensive data it consists for later consumption.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Put **Show** on field, then remove "title" field and add **Path** field

[image]

and if you want result be Absolute Url  on **Rewrite** secion Check *Use absolute link (begins with "http://")*

[image]